# Eclipse : color blocks of code?

Tags: eclipse, colors, visualization

I'm using Eclipse PDT , and since years I've long time wondered if it was possible to color (highlight background color or eclipse left side border) blocks of code inside any file , as an easy visual helper ? 
it's not coloring the code but more personnaly building blocks by theme according to the content ?

Answer (score -1):

Look under: 
Windows->General->editors